# Do UK to Tokyo electrical adapters exist?

Tags: electrical

As part of my upcoming internship program in Tokyo, I am in need of adapters suitable for the Tokyo region. Given that I currently reside in the UK, I specifically require adapters compatible with the standard UK to Tokyo socket configuration. Despite my search on Amazon, I have been unable to locate suitable options. I would greatly appreciate assistance in identifying sources for these adapters.

Items will arrange from:
Phone (Can work off USB C or A charging)
Gaming Laptop (Only works with a standard plug)
Multi charging adaptor has 4 USB slot's (Only works with a standard plug).

Comment: what devices are you expecting to bring along? (and what are the input voltage ranges and frequencies listed on their labels) That will affect the answer

Comment: For a simple adapter that just changes the plug, can probably make one yourself.  The problem that the UK has 220 volt system and Tokyo/Japan has a 100 volt system.  The good thing is that what you mentioned, usually works with any voltage, but do need to check if that is true.  They should have labels stating 100v to 220v or similar.  A fast search for japan receptacle showed a UK to Japan adapter.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about consumer electronics, not home improvement.

Comment: This would be a good question for Travel.SE... Although I'd be surprised if there wasn't an answer there already.

Comment: We spend a lot of time in Europe and travel with a couple US power strips with EU plugs on them (an easy DIY project). I also have strips with Chinese plugs on them. Beyond outlet conversion, this mitigates the fact there are never enough outlets in hotels or peoples' homes (or your eventual accommodation in Japan).

All modern chargers don't really care what voltage you feed them, notably your laptop, iPad, phone & camera chargers. Do check, though, to be sure they say 100-240V.

Comment: spent too long editing

We spend a lot of time in Europe and travel with a couple US power strips with EU plugs on them (an easy DIY project). I also have strips with Chinese plugs on them, and even a couple with UK plugs. This also mitigates the fact there are never enough outlets in hotels or peoples' homes.

All modern chargers can handle 100-240V, notably your laptop, iPad, phone & camera chargers. Do check, though, to be sure.

So buy a couple outlet strips and put Japanese plugs on them and keep using your UK chargers. Get long cords as outlets never seem to be where you want them.

Answer (score 1):

- Phone

  - Get a new USB charger in Japan. They tend to be cheap. 10£ will get you a reputable brand charger.
- Laptop

  - Check that your power supply supports 100V input. It probably has a [*Mickey Mouse plug*](https://www.ebay.com/itm/303659301541), which can be had cheaply almost everywhere - or perhaps even for free at your place of internship. Most companies have a ton of such cables somewhere.
- Multi charging adapter

  - Pick up a new one in Japan. Such devices are cheap.

In total this should be <30£ for you to replace. Adapters are inconvenient, unsafe and bulky.

Comment: I would rather not get a new one as my one at home is like £30 alone, it's a good brand so I would rather get a plug that can adapt it, this laptop will be a mid range so it will be a bit more beefy than say a low gaming laptop so something like an I5 or a ryzen 5 as this is an I7 with a 20 or 30 series GPU.

Comment: If your phone charger is more than 10W, and mine frex is 40, a plug adapter will serve a lot better than a cheap checkout-aisle charger.

Comment: @JaegerGRStratton Replace the *cable* for your laptop charger. Not your laptop or your laptop charger. That cable doesn't matter at *all* for performance.

Comment: @jay613 Used to be true. [Nowadays you can get 20+W chargers from reputable brands for <20$](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/askstorm-23w-usb-charger-white-10461190/).

Comment: If your internship is more than a few weeks I agree that a new AC cable for your laptop charger and a *good* new phone charger are your best bet, avoiding annoying double adapters dangling loosely from walls for an extended period.  All these plug adapters tend to make loose unreliable connections.  For an extended stay, avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have some very good information. But I think a little understanding of what is actually going on with "adapters" will help.

There are 3 basic things that determine a particular country or region's AC power supply:

- Frequency - 50 Hz or 60 Hz

This is not an issue for *most* modern electronics (computers, monitors, etc.) but is important for appliances with AC motors (e.g., washing machine, plug-in power tools). If a device says 50/60 then it doesn't matter. If it says 50 or 60 and you are going to a location that has the other frequency then it *may* be a problem. US/Canada is 60 Hz. Most of Europe and a lot of other places is 50 Hz. Japan actually has some 50 Hz and some 60 Hz!

- Plug Configuration

A simple adapter *only* converts the physical plug configuration. Which is easy and inexpensive to do. But if you have an issue with frequency or, more likely, voltage, then a simple adapter is actually *dangerous* because you may think things will work and find that they partially work or (some 240V devices on 100V supply) don't work very well or (100V device on 240V supply) **die a violent and fiery death**. So do **NOT** use a plug adapter unless you first verify the voltage.

- Voltage

This is the main thing, most of the time. Most of the world is in the 100V - 125V range (Japan 100V, US/Canada 120V, etc.) or 220V - 250V range (most of Europe and other places). The US/Canada is actually an interesting one because it has both 120V and 240V typically available in a house but the standard receptacles that are "everywhere" are 120V with 240V usually only for specific high-power appliances.

Most devices can handle a range of voltage, typically at least +/- 5%. A device designed for 220V or 230V will typically handle 220V (sometimes even 208V) to 250V with no ill effects. A device designed for 120V (US/Canada) may work fine on 100V (Japan). But switching between those two ranges requires either a **transformer** or a device that is designed to handle a wide range of voltages.

A lot of modern electronics can handle the wide range - typically computers, chargers (but not all, especially at the low end), monitors, inkjet printers, TVs, etc. But there are some things that absolutely can't - most large appliances with big motors, most heating appliances (hair dryer, toaster), laser printers (which have a fuser that is normally designed for one or the other voltage range). **If your device does not list a wide voltage range (e.g., 100V - 250V) do NOT assume it can handle the "other" voltage range.**

In the end, the advice to get new devices where small (e.g., USB chargers) and adapters or replacement cables where the device can handle the full voltage range (e.g., laptop) makes sense. But check the specifications of the device and think carefully before plugging anything into a simple adapter.

Transformers are available for when the other voltage range is truly needed and the device is too expensive to easily replace, but they are much more expensive than simple plug adapters and you **MUST** watch the power limits. If a transformer is rated to supply 100W and you try to get 300W out of it, you will likely not be successful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you certainly can get a plug adapter to use your UK phone and laptop chargers in Japan.  Make sure those adapters can accept 100V input.  Probably, but check.  Japan uses the same plugs as US.  Buy an adapter in the UK with a 2-pin US plug and 3-pin UK socket.   *Any* universal adapter will work.

[image]

Your phone charger probably doesn't use the UK ground pin.  Your laptop might use the ground pin for DC nose reduction, and it won't have a ground.  Just how bad that is depends on the laptop.

Comment: I have seen the flat 2 Pins but then I have seen the round ones that was mentioned in Japan but I can't find the flat pins as that is what is said is the most common.

Comment: Some miscommunication or misunderstanding here because the adapter you need is the most common, vanilla one on the market.  It's hard to buy an adapter in the UK that *doesn't* do what you want.  Added pic to answer